# Conditional mean

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-expectation, means

Let $X, Y$ be dependent discrete variables. I need to get $E[X|Y]$ and I found a formula 
$$E[Y∣X=x]=E[Y]+ \text{corr}(X, Y) \frac{\sqrt{\text{var}(Y)}}{\sqrt{\text{var}(X)}}(x −E[X]).$$

I can not find out how to get this formula and I am not sure if it works for discrete variables.

Thank you for your suggestions

Comment: If $X=x$ is known, how can the expectation have $X$ in it, an unknown?

Comment: You are right, there should be (x-EX) instead of (X-EX).

Comment: There's an edit link under the question.

Comment: This is the regression equation of $Y$ on $X$ assuming the regression is linear. So this does not hold in general.

Comment: Interesting. Isn't it weird that the expectation $E[Y|X=x]$ depends always linearly on $x$ ? At the end if $Y=f(X)$ with f non-linear $E[f(X)|X]=f(X)$ ? Isn't it this a counterexample ?

Comment: Happy that @StubbornAtom has the same opinion :D

Comment: @Thomas  If $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal, this is a well-known. See page 267 in http://www.math.chalmers.se/~rootzen/highdimensional/SSP4SE-appA.pdf

Comment: @River Li  Good observation :) . Maybe the OP was simply forgetting the hypothesis of joint normality ? In the general case it looks false... it would have been "too good to be true"...

Comment: Probably the equation is true than when (1) $Y=aX+b$, with $X$ arbitrarily distributed (did not do the algebra but looks reasonable), (2) when $X$ and $Y$ are independent (3) when $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal . Do not know if there are other candidates ....

Answer (score 0):

First, plug the definition of of $corr(X,Y) = \frac{cov(X,Y)}{\sigma_{x} \sigma{y}}$ where $\sigma$ denoting the standard deviation. Then, consider X is unknown. We get, linear least mean squared linear estimator of $Y$ based on $X$

$$E(Y∣X)=E(Y)+ \frac{Cov(X,Y)}{Var(X)}(X−E(X)).$$

which works not only for discrete, but also continuous random variables **assuming that variables are linearly dependent. This does not hold in general**. To derive this, assume $Y = a X + b$ and try to minimize the mean squared estimation error

$$E \left[ \left( Y -aX - b \right)^{2} \right]$$

Notice, $b = Y - aX$. So, $b = E \left[ \left( Y -aX \right) \right] =  E \left[ Y \right] - a E \left[ X\right] $

Finally,

$$ E\left[ \left( \left( Y - E\left[Y \right] \right) -a \left( X - E\left[X \right] \right) \right)^{2} \right]  = E\left[ ( \left( Y - E\left[Y \right] \right)^{2} \right]  + -2a  E\left[ ( \left( Y - E\left[Y \right] \right)  ( \left( X - E\left[X \right] \right) \right]   + a^{2} E\left[ ( \left( X- E\left[X \right] \right)^{2} \right] $$

USe the fact, $cov(X,Y) =  E\left[ ( \left( Y - E\left[Y \right] \right)  ( \left( X - E\left[X \right] \right) \right]  $  and then, the variance definition.

$$ \sigma^{2}_{Y} + a^{2}\sigma^{2}_{X} -2a \times cov(X,Y) $$

Equating the quadratic function into 0 results in $a=\frac{cov(X,Y)}{\sigma^{2}_{X}} = \rho \frac{\sigma_{Y}}{\sigma_{X}}$ where $\rho$ is the correlation.

THe intercept is equal to $b= E\left[  Y \right] - \rho \frac{\sigma_{Y}}{\sigma_{X}} E[X]$.

Plugging the parameters into your linear estimator gives us the estimate of Y using X.